# Getting address from latitude and longitude in version 5.1.1

Tags: android

I am new in Android and I am getting stuck in one thing. I am having latitude and longitude and I want to get the address from the latlng. I successfully got the address from the latlng in the higher version like Marshmallow and Nougat but I am having problem in version 5.1.1.

Here my geocoder is not working. I am getting null always. I have seen many answers but there is one common thing Geocoder, If there is any option to get the address without geocoder or with geocoder.

My code is

```
   if (this.geocoder == null) {
        this.geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    }

    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(Double.parseDouble(lat), Double.parseDouble(lng), 1);
            if (!addresses.isEmpty()) {
            address = addresses.get(0).getLocality();  

         PrefsManager.with(this).save(Constants.PREF_ADDRESS,addresses.get(0).
          getLocality());
            return addresses.get(0).getLocality();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Can you share error you got?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(this);
Address address;

try{

    List<Address> adrsList = gcd.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);

    if(adrsList != null && adrsList.size()>0)
    {
        address = adrsList.get(0);
        buffer = new StringBuffer();

        for(int i=0; i<=address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)
        {
            buffer.append(address.getAddressLine(i));
        }

            textView.setText("Address: " + buffer.toString());
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Nearby Location Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error: " + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```